# ui.bootstrap modal rendering entire page blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ui.bootstrap

When I inject ui.bootstrap as a module in my controller, it renders the entire html page blank. Has this happened to anyone or does anyone know why this would occur? Thank you!

```
   (function() {
    angular
        .module("FreshmanApp", ['ui.bootstrap'])
        .controller("ViewStudentProfileController", ViewStudentProfileController);
```

Comment: I am requiring the library in my index file:

Comment: <!-- Angular Libraries -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tlps-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>

Comment: I think this may have to do with the fact that I have multiple controllers but I am not sure